# How to INSERT INTO #TEMPTABLE without deleting the data of the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating code that creates a table called #Transferencia, it has 31 columns.

I made an insert into it to populate 16 of its columns. When I do another insert into to populate more columns, it makes all other values as NULL

Example of my first INSERT INTO

```
INSERT INTO #Transferencia (ID_Cota, CHAVE, CD_Grupo)
SELECT 
      a.id_cota,
      CONCAT(convert(numeric(10,0),(b.CD_Grupo)),'-',a.CD_Cota),
      b.CD_Grupo
```

Example of my second INSERT INTO that deletes my previous one

```
INSERT INTO  #Transferencia (Usuario, NM_Pessoa_Vendedor)
SELECT 
      c.cd_usuario, 
      d.NM_Pessoa
```

When I finish my second INSERT, the columns (ID_Cota, CHAVE, CD_Grupo) become null

Is there any alternative that I can 'populate' those others colunms by a select?

PS: The code is way more complex, I've simplified it for the sake of this question

Comment: An [`INSERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) adds **rows** and any column no values (other than `NULL`) were set are `NULL` in these rows. An `INSERT` doesn't change the values of existing row to `NULL` (or whatever value for that matter). So your impression is wrong. To change the values of columns of existing rows use [`UDPATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want an `update` for the second operation:

```
INSERT INTO #Transferencia (ID_Cota, CHAVE, CD_Grupo)
    SELECT a.id_cota,
          CONCAT(convert(numeric(10,0),(b.CD_Grupo)),'-',a.CD_Cota),
          b.CD_Grupo;
```

Example of my second INSERT INTO that deletes my previous one

```
UPDATE t
    SET Usuario = c.cd_usuario, 
         NM_Pessoa_Vendedor = d.NM_Pessoa
FROM #Transferencia t . . .
     c . . .
     d . . .
```

The `FROM` clause is your query with `JOIN`s and so on.